# After_save, After_create (order) (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

(Ruby on rails)

I have a registration form that saves data from the form to a table and to another table. I use hooks, "`after_save :process_field_to_another_table`"  and "`after_create :send_registration_email`" to send an email to the user after they register.

Unfortunately, "`after_create`" works before "`after_save`", but I need `:send_registration_email` to work after the save process takes place.  I was thinking of running `:process_field_to_another_table` in the "`after_create`", but than it runs twice in a row, which does not make much sense.

Any idea's how I can instruct "`after_save`" to run before "`after_create`" in this instance? or any better recommendations?  I tried "`before_save`" and "`before_create`", but it does not seem to process correctly.

any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the two hooks into one.

```
after_save :foo

def foo
  process_field_to_another_table
  send_registration_email if id_changed?  # id will change only for new record.
end
```

Comment: `id_changed?` is an method in rails or custom method?

Comment: I guess `#{field_name}_changed?` works for `before_save`. Once record is saved it will lost the changes history.

Comment: Have you checked? See this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed

Comment: You can edit your answer to `before_save` but you can't have `id` before creating record. So you can't do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can separate the calls by using a combination of `after_create` and `after_update` callbacks.

```
after_create :process_field_to_another_table, :send_registration_email
after_update :process_field_to_another_table
```

This way, `process_field_to_another_table` is called before `send_registration_email`.

Comment: this solution would cause process_field_to_another_table to run twice, but thank you, I went with id_changed?

Comment: no it won't. after_update will only run when the object is updated and not created.